# jQUERY unexpected string?

Tags: jquery, ajax

**Problem**

I am getting unexpected string error, yet I don't see anything wrong?..

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var search = $("#search");

        $("#bla").click(function() {
            if (search.val() != '') {
                load();
                $.post("ajax_search.php", { search : search.val()}, function(data) {
                    stop_load();
                    $(".result").html(data);
                });
            } 
            else 
            {
                $(".result").html('');
            }
        });
        $("#hover").hover(function() {
            load();
            $.post"ajax_search.php?type=sidebar", { sidebar : seach.val() }, function(get_data) {
                stop_load();
                $("sidebar").html(get_data);
            }
        });     

function load() {
    $('.load').html('<img src="http://i.imgur.com/ZoI4x5I.gif" />');
}
function stop_load(){
    $('.load').html('');
}   
});
```

**Question**

Basically the problem gets fixed after I remove the function that starts in the

```
    $("#hover").hover(function() {
```

This is the error I am getting by the way:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string :29

This is line 29:

```
        });
```

Right before

```
    $("#hover").hover(function() {
```

What is causing this? What I have done wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Check your syntax on the line `$.post "ajax_search.php?type=sidebar", {`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax for your `$.post` is incorrect.  You're missing both an opening and closing parenthesis.

```
$("#hover").hover(function() {
    load();
//        v-- opening parathesis here
    $.post("ajax_search.php?type=sidebar", { sidebar : seach.val() }, function(get_data) {
        stop_load();
        $("sidebar").html(get_data);
//   v-- closing here
    });
});
```

Comment: Oh, I missed it.. I don't believe I didn't see that.. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Just a suggestion for your future post:

Before posting any `javascript/jQuery` code. Please do the folowing:

1. Visit the site [**jsfiddle.net**](http://jsfiddle.net/)
2. Then, paste your code in the <kbd>javascript</kbd> panel.
3. If it is a jQuery code, select the version from the **Frameworks & Extensions** box on right-side.
4. Then, click on the button at the top, named <kbd>JSHint</kbd>.
5. If there is any error, you will get to know them as red dots on right side.
6. Fix them and again click on <kbd>JSHint</kbd>.
7. Finally, if you get a message like below :

> JSLint Valid! Good work! Your JavaScript code is perfectly valid.

Then run the code on your local machine once again and still if you are getting any error, then post your question on SO. No offence!

Answer (score 2):

you are missing `(` and `)`

```
 $.post("ajax_search.php?type=sidebar", { sidebar : seach.val() }, function(get_data) {
                stop_load();
                $("sidebar").html(get_data);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `post()` method is missing parens.

This:

```
$.post "ajax_search.php?type=sidebar", {
    sidebar: seach.val()
},
```

Should be

```
$.post("ajax_search.php?type=sidebar", {
    sidebar: seach.val()
}),
```

If you're not using an IDE that shows you JS errors, I suggest you check the console on whatever web browser you're using, or even pop your JS into a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and click JSHint.